# JavaScript Fetch Code Works in Postman, but not Google Script Editor

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

This JavaScript Fetch code returns the data I need in Postman. But, I am trying to get this code to work in Google Script Editor for my google sheet, and it is giving me the following error:

ReferenceError: Headers is not defined line 3.

I am brand new to coding, so please bear with me.

Any idea what's wrong here?

POSTMAN CODE:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");

var raw = "{\n    \"id\": 1,\n    \"jsonrpc\": \"1.0\",\n    \"method\": \"getbeaconbeststatedetail\",\n    \"params\": []\n}";

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://mainnet.incognito.org/fullnode", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

EDIT:

I have tried to update this:

```
       function myFunction() {
        var data = {
          'request': {
        'id': '1',
        'jsonrpc': '1.0',
        'method': 'getbeaconbeststatedetail',
        'params': []
            }
      };
      var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
      var options = {
        'method' : 'GET',
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': "text/plain", 'Accept': "text/plain"},
      'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'contentType' : 'application/json',
        'body' : payload
      };
    
      var url = "https://mainnet.incognito.org/fullnode";
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      var txt= response.getContentText();
      var d=JSON.parse(txt);

var sh1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet14"); 
for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
 sh1.getRange(1, 1).setValue(d);
}

}
```

But, I am still getting the following error:

Exception: Request failed for https://mainnet.incognito.org returned code 400

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal from your question. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Sorry. I will re-write my original question.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your answer. I think that your script might be for Javascript. The base of Google Apps Script is Javascript. But in this case, `new Headers()` and `fetch` cannot be used. I think that this is the reason of your error message. But when your script is considered as Javascript, the script is not correct. So I cannot still understand what you want to do. I apologize for this. So can I provide more information for correctly understanding your situation and goal?

Comment: I updated my script, but it's still not displaying any info on my google sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to make an HTTP request from Google Apps Script, you have to use the [`UrlFetchApp()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl) method.

As @Tanaike points out, GAS is based in JS but not all JS functions are allowed. However GAS does have many services to integrate with G Suite products, and external APIs or services. One very useful service is [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) which allows you to perform *any* type of Http request.

### For example:

```js
// Make a GET request with headers.
var options = {
     "method" : "GET",
     "headers" : {
       "Content-Type" : "text/plain",
       "API_KEY": "dummydummy"
     }
   };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.myawesomeapi.com/get", options);
```

You can also make POST or other requests. Please refer to the examples in the documentation for use cases.

#### Update:

You are receiving the 400 "Bad request" error from the "fullnode" endpoint because it requires a POST request with a payload.

```js
function fetchFullNode() {
  var url = "https://mainnet.incognito.org/fullnode";
  
  var data = {
    "jsonrpc":"1.0",
    "method":"getblockchaininfo",
    "params":"",
    "id":65
  };
  
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var txt= response.getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(txt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aerials. That is similar to what I have been using in the past, but it does not work in this scenario. What am I missing? I updated my code.

Comment: You do a poorly written requestOptions object. But I believe you are getting the 400 because the Url "https://mainnet.incognito.org/fullnode" is giving it to you. Try going to that Url in your browser.

Comment: Hey Aerials. I did some more searching and found a couple of posts that seem closer to what I'm trying to do. I updated the code, but it's still not pulling any info. Do you see anything wrong?

Comment: You are saying your request failed for a url different than the one you are requesting in your fetch call.

Comment: Sorry. Let me back up. The URL I'm looking for data from is "https://mainnet.incognito.org/committees". This URL loads fine. When I inspect it though, the source is "https://mainnet.incognito.org/fullnode". I tried applying your code above, but I am getting a request failed 400 code. The only thing I did different is there is no aPI Key.

Comment: You are making a bad request using GET. The content from "fullnode" is being requested via POST and sending json content in the body of the request. I updated my answer, with the POST request you need.